# Manga where a boy raised by animals in a dystopian world needs to find berries to unite carnivores and herbivores

Tags: story-identification, manga

I've read this manga years ago and I'd like to read it again but I cant remember the title but I do remember that at the start of the manga that the boy is raised by monkeys or some type of small anthropomorphic animals in a world of anthropomorphic animals and comes across a black panther and eventually become friends and the end goal is to find special berries that both carnivores and herbivories can eat to live together in peace, dose anyone know the title of this manga?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?  Do you remember where?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [Beastars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beastars)

> In a modern and civilized world populated by anthropomorphic animals, there is a cultural divide between the herbivorous animals and the carnivorous animals